# Does SVN allow commit and push?

Tags: git, svn, mercurial

I haven't worked with SVN in years. Now I have to. With SVN do you get a 'local' copy that you work against and then when you have things right do you push them out to the rest of the team? Or is commit all you have? Meaning that you work on something and risk losing it until it's correct and ready to be committed?

I hate SVN and I remember always hating SVN.

I have to use SVN is there some way to make it better? Can I use Mercurial or GIT at the same time on the same repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use GIT at the same time on the same repo?

Yes you can. Git provides a way to interact with SVN repositories - see [`git svn`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) commands.

In short:

`git svn clone <url>` clones a subversion repository

`git svn fetch` fetches the latest changes

`git svn dcommit` pushes your changes to the subversion repository.

The git book has a chapter on the subject: http://git-scm.com/book/ch8-1.html#Getting-Started

Answer (score 1):

My answer is probably similar to gbjbaanb's one, but I'll stress branches.

If you want to make something immediately available for the whole team - commit to the trunk.

If you want to do a task in several commits and do not want to publish intermediate/unstable state, create a branch, make those commits there and then merge it to the trunk. Making branches is cheap and merging in SVN is not that hard as people usually tell ;)

Answer (score 0):

commit is all you have. Its not bad, I never quite saw the point of local commits - they're just there as a convenience to you in case you wanted to revert some work you're progressing. My workflow tends to be: write some small piece of code, make sure it works, commit it and move on to another piece. All this on a branch anyway so its not going to impact anyone other than my team mates (who will want my changes anyway, assuming they work).

Committing to a central repo does have the advantage that your work is safe. No worries over having your laptop stolen after you've coded all that work on that plane :)

There is talk of introducing shelving for SVN, probably for the next version, which would solve your need to commit without committing.

Comment: "I never quite saw the point of local commits". 
It requires internet!

Comment: @KushagraGour considering how many people want to make loads of local commits and then rebase them into 1 commit to send upstream... I'd say that feature is a small convenience rather than something essential to workflow!